# add ads on web apps

Tags: android, iphone, ios, web-applications

I am properly using adMob and iAd on my native apps. However I am unable to find a good solution for webapps. Assuming that adSense is not allowed for webapps, which services can be use for it? Thank you

Comment: http://googlemobileads.blogspot.com/2011/09/admob-is-for-mobile-app-developers.html. You can definitely use adsense for web apps.

Comment: Link talks about admob and adsense difference but as I said and already tried, adsense needs to spider the content of website and that is why is not suitable for dynamical webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use all types of the [publisher services](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/e4JOUP6zHQc) given by various companies but the thing is we need safe and reliable web apps which gives us Quality with corporate look.
For enhanced web applications development and maintenance you need some training and basics of web technologies. I referred the best information at VRM infotech's website and they are providing free information about web apps and development. For more details please feel free to contact the [pioneers in Web Application development](http://www.vrminfotech.com/services/application-development/default.htm)